# Package not found in maven jetty plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty, maven-plugin

When i try to run jetty maven plugin(mvn jetty:run) I have received this error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

D:\projects\Projekt\src\main\java\Runner.java:[18,22] package org.apache.uima does not exist
```

This package use class Runner, and it seems that it was not found, how can i add it?
I have tried to use <webAppConfig>, but it doesn't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update2: Uima is now available in a publicly available Maven repo, no need to configure your repository list.

Update: Uima *is* available on the Apache's m2 http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating-repository. You'll need to configure your settings to [reference the repository](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/appendix-settings-sect-settings-repository.html) and add the dependency(ies) to your pom.

The dependency for uima-core looks like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
  <!--note there are several other uima jars you may want to reference-->
  <artifactId>uimaj-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.5.v20170502</version>
            <configuration>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>9999</port>
                </httpConnector>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: my version of jetty pluggin.
And i run by another command line command:
**mvn jetty:run-war**